# How do I retrieve specific data from one table based on a selection in another table?

Tags: sql, c++builder

From Borland C++ Builder, I have two Paradox tables: one has manufacturer names, the other the manufacturer names along with their products. The data is set in two DBGrids. In the manufacturer grid I want to be able to select a manufacturer and have that manufacturer and its related products show up in the other grid. I am new to this. I searched the database here and found some things to try, but...I think I'm just doing it wrong. 
I have two tables and two datasources, each set taking a grid. I placed an SQL Query on the form and gave it this:

```
select customers.cust
from products inner join products on customers.cust = products.custid
```

And while the query doesn't fail, it doesn't do anything for me, either. Will someone please help me understand this? Thank you.

Comment: Wrong title for the question: you really want a `JOIN`, but your title asks for `IN` as in `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cust IN (SELECT DISTINCT custid FROM products)`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Paradox but try this:

```
select customers.cust
from customers
inner join products on customers.cust = products.custid
```

currently it looks like you are joining products with itself which doesn't seem to be what you want to do.